# How to extract key values from CSV in Talend

Tags: csv, etl, key-value, talend

I have csv data file as below :

```
 `Column1`                  `Column2`                    `Column3`           
    
{'name':'Steve Jobs'}   ,    {'first_name':'Steve'}  , {'last_name':'Jobs'} 
    
{'name':'Mark Zuckerberg'} ,  {'first_name':'Mark'}  ,  {'last_name':'Zuckerberg'}

{'name':'Steve Jobs'}   ,    {'first_name':'Steve'}  , {'last_name':'Jobs'}
```

I want my data as below using Talend Tool:

```
`name`          `first_name`    `last_name`

Steve Jobs       Steve          Jobs

Mark Zuckerberg  Mark          Zuckerberg

Steve Jobs       Steve         Jobs
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `substring()` and `indexOf()` functions to achieve this.

Explanation:

1. Since Key and Value is separated by `:` we can substring after the `:`and before `}`
2. To get the position of then `:` and `}`, we can use `indexOf` function

Below is the condition used in tMap for three columns,

```
row1.Column1.substring(row1.Column1.indexOf(":")+2, row1.Column1.indexOf("}")-1) 
row1.Column2.substring(row1.Column2.indexOf(":")+2, row1.Column2.indexOf("}")-1) 
row1.Column3.substring(row1.Column3.indexOf(":")+2, row1.Column3.indexOf("}")-1)
```

Result,

[image]

Comment: Hey thank you so much. It helped me a lot. This is applicable for few rows. What if I have more number of rows.Then is there any component in that case?

Comment: sorry *columns not rows. If I have more than 15 columns. How can I handle that?

Comment: You have to use same logic for all the columns

Comment: I have a column where there is 4 to 5 key value pairs in a single cell, How will I retrieve those values into separate columns.

Comment: Can you provide the example?

Comment: ROW VALUE = { 'name' : 'Steve Jobs' , 'location' : 'America' , 'age' : '56' }. This is single row value for one column.  Now I want separate columns as name, location, age.

Comment: Can you ask this as a separate question, will work on it and help you. Also include more data

Comment: yeah I have posted